# Delete WordPress post from front end

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have duilt a custom post type and added it to a tab on the profile page. I want to add a button to delete the post if the post author is logged in. I tried several methods but couldn't find a way to delete it since I am not trying to delete it from the single post page. Can anyone direct me on how to achieve this?

```
//function to print publish button
function show_publish_button(){
        Global $post;
        //only print fi admin
            echo '<form id="myForm" name="front_end_publish" method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$post->ID.'">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="delete" class="btn" style="margin-left:2px;background:#f5f5f5;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>delete</button>
        </form>';}

// Adding Manage Event TAB content
function manage_events_content() { 
   $type = 'events';

                $args = array (
                 'post_type' => $type,
                 'name' => $title,      
                 'author' => bp_displayed_user_id(),
                 'post_status' => 'publish',
                 'paged' => $paged,
                 'posts_per_page' => 10,
                 'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
                );
    
                $temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use  
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
                if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        
                
                
                echo '<div style="background-color:#fff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 20px">
                           <div>
                            <div>
                                <h4 style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px; text-transform: capitalize">Event Name: 
                                <a style="color:#5a5a5a;" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>
                            </h4></div> 
                            
                            <div>
                                <h4>
                                    Number of tickets available: <span>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "number-of-ticket-available", true) . '</span>
                                </h4>
                                <h4>
                                    Number of tickets available: <span>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "number-of-confirmed-attendees", true) . '</span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div>
                                <h4>
                                    Start Date: <span>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "event-anfang", true) . '</span>
                                </h4>
                                <h4>
                                    End Date: <span>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "event-ende", true) . '</span>
                                </h4>
                                
                            </div>' . show_publish_button() . '
                                
                            </div>
                            
                                </div>';     
                        
    
                    endwhile;
    
    
    
                else :
                    echo '<h4>You dont have any events</h4>';
         
                endif;
                $wp_query = $temp;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_delete_post_link/

Comment: @AnoopD i tried it, but what happens is it deletes the entire page instead of that single post

Comment: Well then you probably did not pass it the correct post id.